# How can i get the users corresponding file saved in storage using Firestore in java script

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

i wanted to create a table list from Firestore which has a field of attachment which users upload during registration the file is saved with their uid as a name so i want to get the image they uploaded which corresponds to the user.

this is the table html

```
        <table class="fl-table">
            <thead>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email Address</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th>Country Of Residence</th>
                <th>Attached File</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody1"></tbody>
        </table>
```

this is the html file and i wanted to put the file link or a button which opens the corresponding image

this is the javascript

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let db = getFirestore();


var attendantNumber = 0;
var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody1');

function AddItemToTable(fname, lname, email, phoneNumber, country, "attachedfile"){

    let trow = document.createElement('tr');
    let td1 = document.createElement('td');
    let td2 = document.createElement('td');
    let td3 = document.createElement('td');
    let td4 = document.createElement('td');
    let td5 = document.createElement('td');
    let td6 = document.createElement('td');
    let td7 = document.createElement('td');

    td1.innerHTML = ++attendantNumber;
    td2.innerHTML = fname;
    td3.innerHTML = lname;
    td4.innerHTML = email;
    td5.innerHTML = phoneNumber;
    td6.innerHTML = country;
    td7.innerHTML = nation;

    trow.appendChild(td1);
    trow.appendChild(td2);
    trow.appendChild(td3);
    trow.appendChild(td4);
    trow.appendChild(td5);
    trow.appendChild(td6);
    trow.appendChild(td7);

    tbody.appendChild(trow);

    console.log("a");

}

function AddAllItemsToTable(TheAttendanct) {
    attendantNumber = 0;
    tbody.innerHTML = "";
    TheAttendanct.forEach(element => {
        AddItemToTable(element.FirstName, element.LastName, element.Email, element.PhoneNumber, element.Country, element.Nationality);
    });
    console.log("B");
}


async function GetAllData() {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "attendants"));
    var attendants = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        attendants.push(doc.data());
    });

    AddAllItemsToTable(attendants);
}

window.onload = GetAllData;
```

Edited

this is my upload function

```
 async function UploadAttachment() {
              var selectedFile = attachment.files[0];
              var fileName = user.uid
          
              const metaData = {
                contentType: selectedFile.type
              }
          
              const storage = getStorage();
              const storageRef = sRef(storage, "attachments/" + fileName)
          
              const UploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, selectedFile, metaData);
          
              UploadTask.on('state-changed', (snapshot) => {
                var uploadProgress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                persentage.innerHTML = "Upload" + uploadProgress + "%";
              },(error) => {
                alert('error: Image Not Uploaded')
              },
              ()=>{
                getDownloadURL(UploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadUrl) => {
                  console.log(downloadUrl);
                })
              }
              );
            }
```

Comment: What is your code of uploading file and adding its download url to firestore

Comment: please refer the edit @SheikhHaziq

Comment: Do you add this download url to firestore

Comment: yes i do @SheikhHaziq

Comment: I found a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031657/how-to-visualize-filestorage-content-of-firebase-in-table-at-the-view) in Stackoveroverflow . However, it is with Reactjs code, but you may have a look at it to get some idea on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check does it return data here

```
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    // Print data to console
    console.log(doc.data());
    attendants.push(doc.data());
});
```

Comment: Provide the screenshot of console result